# Set up CS4270 audio codec chip as ALSA device on Raspberry CM4

Tags: linux, audio, kernel, codec, alsa

I’ve got a Raspberry CM4 connected with a Cirrus Logic CS4270 chip that should provide audio I/O ( CS4270 Datasheet: https://media.digikey.com/pdf/data%20sheets/cirrus%20logic%20pdfs/cs4270.pdf ). The CS4270 is set in Software Mode (I2C protocol), with the following pinout:

| CS4270 | CM4 |
| --- | --- |
| RST | GPIO22 |
| SDIN | GPIO21 |
| SDOUT | GPIO20 |
| LRCK | GPIO19 |
| SCLK | GPIO18 |
| M0 | GPIO3 (SCL1) |
| M1 | GPIO2 (SDA1) |
| I2S/*LJ | GND |
| MDIV1 | 3V3 |
| MDIV2 | GND |
| MCLK | (Input from external 22.5792MHZ oscillator) |

I can find the CS4270 codec implementation inside the linux kernel code on “/sound/soc/codecs/cs4270.c” ( https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/sound/soc/codecs/cs4270.c ). However, I’m not capable to set it up to work (e.g. I’ve built a linux kernel to get all the modules, but “snd-soc-cs4270.ko” is not present in the built modules.)

My question is:

How can make the CS4270 work with ALSA as an audio device?

Sorry for the vague question, but I really don’t know how to proceed.

Best,
FD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the solution myself:

CS4270 chip codec is not enabled by default. To enable it, inside the main directory of raspberry linux kernel (in my case rpi-5.15.y), do:

- "make menuconfig" to build the kernel configuration menu
- Inside menuconfig menu navigate to ”Device Drivers” -> “Sound card support” -> ”Advanced Linux Sound Architecture” -> ”ALSA for SoC audio support” -> “Codec Drivers”
- Allow Cirrus cs4270 codec to be built as a module (M)
- Save and exit
- Make as your needs (select all other configuration options as defaults if asked)

The .ko file is then successfully compiled.